# Prolog how to store first 3 elements in a list into another list

Tags: prolog

I tried something like this:
said path = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[5,6]]

```
first_three(N,[H|T],[H|_]):- not(N=0),N is N-1, first_three(N,T,L).
```

then I call first_three(3, path, Y) but it return no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a base case (when N = 0). And you also need to instantiate a new fresh variable to assign the predecesor of N, and finally you also need to return the result of the recursion (the [H|L] in the head of the clasuse):

```
first_three(0,_,[).
first_three(N,[H|T],[H|L]):- 
  N\=0,
  N1 is N-1, 
  first_three(N,T,L).
```

Of course, you can also just write something like this:

```
first_three([One,Two, Three|_], [One,Two, Three]).
```

and call it:

```
first_three(Path, Y).
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `N is N - 1` can't possibly succeed - `N` is not a variable in the imperative programming language sense, so you don't store values in it, it can be assigned only once, so to speak - so you may want to introduce a new variable and call something like `N1 is N - 1`, and subsequently use `N1` in the recursive call to `first_three`. Then, the last argument to that recursive call comes out of nowhere, so you may need to pay attention to it too. As a last suggestion, try to split the predicate in two clauses: the first to manage the elementary basic case where `N` is `0`, the second to manage the meaty cases, building on top of the other.

Oh, and since `N` is a variable quantity, I would suggest to use a different name rather than the misleading `first_three` for your predicate.